# Why is block level element contained inside inline-block level element displayed as inline?

Tags: html, css

I created a fiddle just to demonstrate the question:
https://jsfiddle.net/vanillasnake21/bf0j0v5L/

```
<a>
  <span> close </span>
</a>
```

The `<a>` tag is set to `display:inline-block` and the `<span>` is `display:block`, when the `<span>` is not enclosed by the `<a>` tag it spans the entire width of the page as I would expect a block level element should. When enclosed with the a tag as shown above it just looks like it's being displayed as inline even though examining it in dev tools still shows it as a block element. Why does this happen and why doesn't the `<span>` span the entire width of the `<a>` element?

Comment: it is displayed as block, try to add width and or height, and see the different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no place for your `span` element to take the entire width of the page. Technically, you are rendering a *block* level element inside an *inline block* element. So your block level element does take 100% of the parent width.

Since there is no `width` defined for the parent `inline-block`, it takes whatever space it gets inside the `inline-block` element. To demonstrate this, if I assign some `width` to the `inline-block` element of yours, the `span` will take all the available width of the parent element.

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 7em;
  width: 400px; /* define some width here to the parent */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 7em;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span> close </span>
</a>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bf0j0v5L/1/)

Here, your `span` takes all the width it gets as you have assigned a `width` to your parent inline-block element.

---

Another example, added `box-sizing` to count the `padding` inside the element, and appended `width: 100%;` to the parent element.

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
a{
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em 7em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span> close </span>
</a>
```

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/bf0j0v5L/2/)

---

Note that rendering a *block* level element inside an *inline block* element will not force the parent element to take all the available horizontal space on the document.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great explanation.